# Runtime compiler problems with lambda expression in CSHTML file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two `cshtml` views in my C# ASP.NET MVC5 project.  These views handle a user profile and a company profile.

I am making editors for the fields so that the user can fill out their profile.

In the user profile view, the lambda expressions in the editors fails to compile in the browser.
The relevant part of the user view:

```
@model Project.Models.UserProfileViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Profile";
}
<h2>User Profile</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm( "UserProfile", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor( model -> model.Salutation )
        @Html.EditorFor( model -> model.Salutation )
    </div>
}
```

And the matching part of the company view:

```
@model Project.Models.CompanyProfileViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Step 2:  Company Profile";
}
<h2>Company Profile</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm( "CompanyProfile", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyName)
    </div>
}
```

The user view error is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the
>   current context

The company view works just fine.  For what it's worth, the user view works just fine when I use `@Html.EditorForModel()`.

I don't see any difference between my views, so why is the lambda expression failing the JIT compilation in only one view?

As a side issue, Razor v3 is not highlighting my views nor providing Intellisense.  But that's a question for another post.

Comment: replace  model -> model.Salutation  with  model => model.Salutation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-> does not equal =>.

See it now? :)

It should be:

```
@Html.LabelFor( model => model.Salutation )
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.Salutation )
```

Comment: "Have you ever spent more than one hour searching for a single-character error?  More than four hours?  More than a day?  More than two days?  Did the first person you show it to find it immediately?"

Comment: Been there dozens of times.  Can't see the forest for the trees :).

Comment: Questions 477-481 on The Hacker Test v1.0. http://www.hungry.com/~jamie/hacktest.text